# Match a specific string with several constants using Regex

Tags: regex

There are now different requirements to the regex I am looking for, and it is too complex to solve it on my own.

I need to search for a specific string with the following requirements:

1. String starts with "fu:  and ends with "
2. In between those start and end requirements there can be any other string which has the following requirements:

   2.1. Less than 50 characters

   2.2. Only lower case

   2.3. No trailing spaces

   2.4. No space between "fu:  and the other string.

The result of the regex should be cases where case no' 1 matches but cases no' 2./2.1/2.2/2.3/2.4 don't.

At the moment I have following regex: `"fu:([^"]*?[A-Z][^"]*?)"`,
which finds strings with start with `"fu:` and end with `"` with any upper case inbetween like this one:

```
"fu:this String is wrong cause the s from string is upper case"
```

I hope it all makes sense, I tried to get into regex but this problem seems to complex for someone who is not working with regex every day.

[Edit]

Apparently I was not clear enough. I want to have matches which are "wrong".
I am looking for the complement of this regex: "fu:(?:[a-z][a-z ]{0,47}[a-z]|[a-z]{0,2})"

some examples:

Match: "fu: this is a match"

Match: "fu:This is a match"

Match: "fu:this is a match "

NO Match: "fu:this is no match"

Sorry, its not easy to explain :)

Comment: replace A-Z with a-z to get lower case. Use [a-z ]{0,50)  to get 50 lowercase characters or spaces.  Do you allow punctuation?  What language are you using?

Comment: What is the language anyway? Is this full PCRE regex, or subset?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
"fu:([a-z](?:[a-z ]{0,48}[a-z])?)"
```

This will match any string that begins with `"fu:` and ends with a `"` and the string between those will contain 1-50 characters - only lower-case and not able to begin with a space nor have trailing spaces.

```
"fu:                    # begins with "fu:
(                       # group to match
    [a-z]               # starts with at least one character
    (?:                 # non-matching sub-group
        [a-z ]{0,48}    # matches 0-48 a-z or space characters
        [a-z]           # sub-group must end with a character
    )?                  # group is not required
)
"                       # ends with "
```

**EDIT**: In the event that you need an empty-string to match too, i.e. the full string is `"fu:"`, you can add another `?` to the end of the matching-group in the regex:

```
"fu:([a-z](?:[a-z ]{0,48}[a-z])?)?"
```

I've kept the two regexes separated (one that allows 1-50 characters in the string and one that allows 0-50) to show the minor difference.

**EDIT #2**: To match the inverse of the above, i.e. - to find all strings that do not match the required format, you can use:

```
^((?!"fu:([a-z](?:[a-z ]{0,48}[a-z])?)?").)*$
```

This will explicitly match *any* line that does not match that pattern. This will consequently also match lines that do not contain `"fu:` - if that matters.

The only way I can figure out to truly match the opposite of the above and still include the anchors of `"fu:` and `"` are to explicitly attempt to match the rules that fail:

```
"fu:([^a-z].*|[^"]{51,}|[a-z]([^"]*?[A-Z][^"]*?)+|[a-z ]{0,49}[ ])"
```

This regex will match anything that starts with *not* a lowercase `a-z` character, any string that's longer than 50 characters, any string that contains an uppercase letter, or any string that has trailing whitespace. For each additional rule, you'll need to update the regex to match the opposite of what's needed.

My recommendation is, in whatever language you're using, to match all input strings that actually follow your requirements - and if there are no matches then that string must violate your rules.

Comment: Not sure whether OP wants `"fu:"` to be matched, since it fulfills all conditions. The rest looks good.

Comment: No, what I meant is the case where the other string (as OP defines) is an empty string. I'm not sure whether the OP wants it to be matched

Comment: This one exactly gives me the "correct" matches. Now I "just" need the complement of this regex. I basically want to have all matches which are wrong. for example I want to have a match on this string:
"fu: Wrong "  but not on this one" "fu:wrong".
Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: Is the string allowed to have spaces in it?  The above regex doesn't allow spaces.

Comment: @Dave The regex above is allowed to have spaces; the `[a-z ]` matches characters `a-z` or ` `.

Comment: @goTAN What language are you using the regex in? Is it possible to simply use something similar to `!Regex.IsMatch(...)` instead?

Comment: @newfurniturey thank you very much the last one works perfectly.
Tbh I dont have any language yet :) I am testing the regex in sublime text 2. But I guess I will use python. I want to check my sourcefiles before building with this regex, so I guess I will run a python script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"fu:(?:[a-z][a-z ]{0,47}[a-z]|[a-z]?)"
```

Comment: This looks good now. `{0,2}` is a bit redundant, since the 2 case is matched by previous case, but doesn't make it wrong.

Comment: You're right. This leads my to @newfurniturey's solution :). +1 to him!

Answer (score 0):

```
"fu:([^A-Z" ](?:[^A-Z"]{0,48}[^A-Z" ])?)"
```

The above regex should match the specified requirements.

Comment: The character groups will allow number in the string.

Comment: @nhahtdh Correct. The question does not specify that numbers are banned.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question of the OP, but it seems that it says only lower case (and spaces - from the example) is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably what you need

```
"fu:([a-z](?:[a-z ]{,48}[a-z])?)"
```